# Delete number in String containing a bunch of different numbers

Tags: php

I have a String which looks like this "int1 int2 int3 int4 int5 int6 int7 int8 /*...*/ intn-1 intn" and I'm trying to delete one of the number (let's say 12 here). In order to do that, I'm currently doing something like this:

```
$table = explode(' ', $my_string); 
$key = array_search($int_to_delete, $table); 
array_splice($table, $key, 1); 
$my_string = implode(' ', $table);
```

Is there a function to do that? :)
Something like "delete $needle if it's at the beginning, the end or surrounded by $delimiter (in my example ' ')" ?

Thx all :D

Comment: you could use a regular expression preg_replace() or str_replace();  `preg_replace('/int12\s/', '', $my_string)` or `str_replace('int12 ', '', $my_string);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Have a try using regular expression based string substitution:

```
<?php
$subject = '8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17';
$pattern = sprintf('/\s?(%s)\s?+/Uu', 12);
$output = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $subject);
var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(38) "8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17"
```